# my portion of code doesnt work

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to distribute a value into 3 input fields so the sum of all 3 cannot exceed the set dynamic value. I tried it in JSFiddle it works fine. Here is the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/k2QVV/

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var 
total = parseInt($('#quantityRequired').text()),
inputs = $('input[type="number"]');

inputs
.attr('max', total)
.change(function() {

    //Make sure that current value is in range
    if($(this).val() > parseInt($(this).attr('max'))) {
        $(this).val($(this).attr('max'));
    } else if ($(this).val() < parseInt($(this).attr('min'))) {
        $(this).val($(this).attr('min'));
    }

    //Get currently available total
    var current = available();

    //Now update max on each input
    $('input').each(function(indx) {
        $(this).attr('max',  parseInt($(this).val()) + total - current);
    });
});
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    Quantity Required : <span id='quantityRequired'>20</span><br />
<input type='number' name='val1' min='0' value='0' required /> <br />
<input type='number' name='val2' min='0' value='0' required /> <br />
<input type='number' name='val3' min='0' value='0' required />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Show us the JSFiddle then.

Comment: The `available()` function you are referencing in your code isn't defined in this code.

Please supply a correct and up to date example of the code you are/were using in both your current site and the jsfiddle.

Comment: 1) You actually call Jquery code before jquery file loaded 2) You call jquery code without putting it inside `$(document).ready(function() {...` handler 3) You call jquery code in elements haven't even added yet. Consider a good tactic to put JS code either in the end of your HTML (before the </body>) or in a file which is then loaded from HTML. Probably JSFiddler auto-loads jquery on its own to give you the correct result.

Comment: this is the jsfiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/k2QVV/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works on jsfiddle because the jQuery lib is loaded before your code is called.
You should load the library before calling your script, by adding this line:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

right after:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```